# Safe/Better SQL Query with Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I wrote two queries doing the same thing, but result on console log is different. Which is better? Are both safe from `SQL` injection?

```
Order.where(user_id: current_user.id).or(Order.where(seller_id: current_user.id))
```

Log:

```
Order Load (0.3ms)
  SELECT "orders".*
  FROM "orders"
  WHERE ("orders"."user_id" = ? OR "orders"."seller_id" = ?)
  ORDER BY "orders"."created_at" DESC
  [["user_id", 1], ["seller_id", 1]]
```

---

```
Order.where("user_id = ? OR seller_id = ?", current_user.id, current_user.id)
```

Log:

```
Order Load (0.3ms)
  SELECT "orders".*
  FROM "orders"
  WHERE (user_id = 1 OR seller_id = 1)
  ORDER BY "orders"."created_at" DESC
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are both safe regarding the SQL injection for several reasons:

1. the variables passed to it is the result of calling `id` on a User object and will always be either `nil` or an `integer` and will never be a string like `1;DELETE FROM users`.
2. the variables are given as arguments to the `where` method, which makes Rails parameterise or sanitize the input for you. If you did some direct string interpolation like `User.where("name = '#{params[:search]}'")` and the end-user submitted `bla';delete from users'` then yeah, SQL injection.

The best option for you is to use the `.or` version which does not use any hard-coded SQL code. It just pass ruby code to the DB adapter you defined and ask it to translate it to SQL.

Comment: While you're largely correct here, there's no guarantee the `id` value is an integer. The model could use a string key here.

Comment: ...But it would be **very** unusual for the user to be able to choose the value of the `id` field! I've never head of a scenario where someone's set the primary key to `"; drop table users;--`!

Comment: *"which makes Rails sanitize the input for you"* -- As you can see from the SQL, Rails has *parameterised* the values rather than sanitising them.